# How to create a java program for establishing connection for PLC?

Tags: java, sockets

Recently I have been working on PLC(programmable logic controller).As I am new to coding I am not able to create a simple connection between PLC and my device. I am using Java Socket Programming for connection but I have no idea how to connect server-side program to client-side program.I am able to create a a program that grabs analog and discrete data points from a PLC using socket. Following is the code for same:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

class PLCServer

{


public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
{

    // IP address of the ethernet card

    String ENBTIP = "192.168.10.14";
    DataInputStream socketReader = null;
    PrintStream socketWriter = null;

    try 
    {
            Socket client = new Socket(ENBTIP, 9100);
            socketReader = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            socketWriter = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection");
            System.out.println("host: 192.168.10.14 port: 9100");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error setting up socket connection: " + e);
            System.out.println("host: 192.168.10.14 port: 9100");
        }
    // Debugging code
    //System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName(ENBTIP).isReachable(10000));
}
}
```

Now i have to create same program for taking analog and discrete data point on the client side but I am got getting how to do it.

Can anybody please give me some guidance?